# Rotate an Image in memory

Tags: java, image, rotation, awt

I keep in memory a list of java.Awt Images and have the need to rotate them. I've read some solutions but they deal with changing the way the image is shown, not really rotating the image itself.
I need to rotate an image itself, not to draw in in a rotated way. How can this be attained?

Comment: Do you want to physically rotate the pixels?  I'm having trouble trying to work out what you trying to achieve?  Are loading images, rotating them in memory and the saving them back out or something??

Comment: AffineTransform, Graphics2D and BufferedImage would be a good starting point.

Comment: I'm acquiring the images from scanner, then i show them on the screen and at the end saving them on disk; i actually need to rotate the pixels.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following code will rotate an image by an arbitrary angle in degrees.

Positive values for `degrees` will rotate the image clockwise, negative values counterclockwise.
The resulting image will be adjusted in size, so that the rotated image fits exactly into it.
I have tested it with `jpg` and `png` image files as input.

```
public static BufferedImage rotateImage(BufferedImage src, double degrees) {
double radians = Math.toRadians(degrees);

int srcWidth = src.getWidth();
int srcHeight = src.getHeight();

/*
 * Calculate new image dimensions
 */
double sin = Math.abs(Math.sin(radians));
double cos = Math.abs(Math.cos(radians));
int newWidth = (int) Math.floor(srcWidth * cos + srcHeight * sin);
int newHeight = (int) Math.floor(srcHeight * cos + srcWidth * sin);

/*
 * Create new image and rotate it
 */
BufferedImage result = new BufferedImage(newWidth, newHeight,
    src.getType());
Graphics2D g = result.createGraphics();
g.translate((newWidth - srcWidth) / 2, (newHeight - srcHeight) / 2);
g.rotate(radians, srcWidth / 2, srcHeight / 2);
g.drawRenderedImage(src, null);

return result;
}
```

Comment: Thanks but this seems to "eat up" some of the pixels for the borders.

Comment: You're welcome. But attention, this only works with square images. (Or with 180 degree ratations), but adjusting the image sizes correctly should not be that challenge. A more direct way, I only have for 360 degree rotations. ;-)

Comment: Now, it was really more than a little challenge to get that image rotation right for arbitrary sized images. Here is what I finally came out with, I updated my answer with the new code. Workes for me like a charm. Special feature: you can also rotate clockwise and counterclockwise. Results for -45 and +135 degrees are the same.